# Remove white space in hidden and display:none input elements

Tags: html, css, input, hidden, space

I've got a few lines that look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="email@email.com" style="display:none" >
```

Each one is adding extra space, even though I've used the type hidden and display:none. I'm starting to think it's something in the CSS (http://www.pastebin.ca/2350649), but after changing up a few things can't find what is causing it either.

The input is all inside a form, if that makes a difference.

Comment: do you have the html also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the input element, but rather the html.  If you have a setup like:

```
text
<input>
more text
```

The newlines/spaces between the text and the input element are rendered.

The simplest solution is of course to just remove that whitespace in your html when it's emitted.  If you can't do that, one trick is to add `font-size: 0` to the container and `font-size ?` to the individual elements to display.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/cs63w/

Answer (score 0):

**step1:** add your codes in a div element with an id tag like this:

```
<div id="remove_br"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="email@email.com" style="display:none" ></div>
```

**step2:** add this jQuery code in your page before `</html>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#remove_br").find('br').remove()
</script>
```

**Note:** don't forget to add this code for calling jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

For beginner programmer: If you don't want to download and host jQuery yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

```
 <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Adding jQuery to Your Web Pages [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp).